# PHP Move main category under subcategory

Tags: php, mysql, recursion

I'm using category tree on MySQL/PHP its works fine but I'm stuck in a problem.

My tables colums/rows;

```
 ID   parent_id      category
----------------------------------
| 1      0        Main Category 1
| 2      0        Main Category 2
| 3      1        Sub Category 1.1
| 4      1        Sub Category 1.2
| 5      2        Sub Category 2.1
| 6      2        Sub Category 2.2
```

This structure works fine, listing, deleting and editing etc. But when a user move a category (under own subcategory) like Main Category 1 to Sub Category 1.2 categories are disappearing.

How can I check or re-organize before update?

Comment: That's a logic flaw. You should not allow a user to prune a "root" of your tree and graft it onto a branch of that same root. In effect you're allowing Minecraft operations - slice out the middle of a tree, and the branches/leaves just magically stay hanging mid-air.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should update its parent_id as well, because I believe that's how it looks at subcategory. However, pay attention to the possibility of making a category its own subcategory. You should check, whether the new parent would be itself.